# Remove rows with value below zero in the column in each list's dataframe in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a large list with 12 elements (dataframes). Each dataframe has the same numer of rows and columns.

I would like to remove all rows which have in the column AMOUNT value < 0.

This has to be done for all dataframes from the list.

Here is an example of the dataframe.

```
df
NAME   TIME  AMOUNT
1       20     456
2       30     -234
3       15     -13
4       12     267
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lapply(our_list, function(X) X[X$AMOUNT >= 0,])

[[1]]
  NAME TIME AMOUNT
1    1   20    456
4    4   12    267

[[2]]
  NAME TIME AMOUNT
2    2   30     23
```

Data:

```
our_list <- list(
  data.frame(
    NAME = 1:4, 
    TIME = c(20L, 30L, 15L, 12L), 
    AMOUNT = c(456L,-234L, -13L, 267L)
  ),
  data.frame(
    NAME = 1:4, 
    TIME = c(20L, 30L, 15L, 12L), 
    AMOUNT = c(-6L, 23L, -13L, -26L)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the tidyverse approach

```
library(tidyverse) # loads the tidyverse

list_of_df <- list_of_df %>% 
  map(., function(x){x %>% filter(AMOUNT >= 0)}) # filters out the values from the AMOUNT column
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way(without the need for other R Packages),
if your dataframe is 'df' and the value you want to filter out negative numbers is 'value'

```
df <- df[value>=0,]
```

This filters the dataframe based on the value column being greater than or equal to zero.
Hope this helps.

Comment: The object the OP wants to filter is a list of dataframes, not a single dataframes. Thanks

Comment: I need to read more carefully.